# no matching function for call to 'DB::add_rec(const char [9], char, int, float)'

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, конструктор

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class church {
char *name;
char school;
unsigned int count;
unsigned short square;
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, church &o1);
friend istream & operator>>(istream &stream, church &o1);
friend void shapka(void);
friend void linebuild(void);
public:
church() { count=0; square=0;}
church(char *a, char b,  int c, float d);
void set(char *a,char ,int ,float );
void get(char *a, char &b,  int &c, float &d);
void show(void);
char  ret_name() {return *name;}
};

void shapka(void)
{
cout<<"_______________________________________________________________\n";
cout<<"|         Буддистские монастыри Японии периода Нара           |\n";
cout<<"|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
cout<<"|  Название  | Школа | Количество монахов | Площадь земли(га) |\n";
cout<<"|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}

void linebuild(void) {
cout<<"\n|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}

class DB {
char title[30];
church *rows[12];
int col;
int sorted;
public:
DB(char *q) {strcpy(title,q); col=0; sorted=0;}
~DB(){if (col) for (int i=0; i<col; i++) delete rows[i];}
void add_rec(char *a, char &b, int &c, float &d);
void del_rec();
void sort_DB();
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, DB &temp);
};

void DB::add_rec(char *a, char &b, int &c, float &d) {
if (col>=12) return;
else col++;
rows[col-1] = new church(a,b,c,d);
sorted=0;
}

void DB::del_rec() {
if (col<=0) return;
delete  rows[col-1];
col--;
}

void DB::sort_DB() {
char s1;
char s2;
if (col<2) return;
church *temp;

for (int i=0; i<col; i++)
for (int j=i+1; j<col; j++) {
s1 = rows[i]->ret_name();
s2 = rows[j]->ret_name();
if (s1 > s2) {
  temp=rows[i];
  rows[i]=rows[j];
  rows[j]=temp;
 }
 }
 sorted=1;
 }

ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, DB &o1) {
stream<<o1.title<<endl;
if (o1.sorted==0) stream<<"Таблица не отсортирована.\n";
else stream<<"Таблица отсортирована.\n";
shapka();
if (!o1.col) stream<<"Таблица пуста.";
else {
for (int i=0; i<o1.col; i++) {
stream<<*o1.rows[i];
}
}
return stream;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, church &o1) {
stream<<"|"<<setw(10)<<o1.name<<"  |  ";
stream<<setw(5)<<o1.school<<"|";
stream<<setw(18)<<o1.count<<"  |";
stream<<setw(17)<<o1.square<<"  |"; 
cout<<endl;
//linebuild();
return stream;
}

church::church(char *a, char b , int c, float d) {
name=new char [strlen(a)+1];
strcpy(name,a);
school=b;
count=c;
square=d;
}

void church::set(char *a,char b,int c,float d) {
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
name[i]=a[i];
}
school=b;
count=c;
square=d;
}

void church::show(void) {
cout<<name<<" ";
cout<<school<<" ";
cout<<count<<" ";
cout<<square<<" "; 
}

void church::get( char * a, char &b, int &c, float &d)
{
strcpy(a,name);
b=school;
c=count;
d=square;
}

  //void linebuild(void) {
  // cout<<"\n|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
  //}

  int main(void) {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char *n;
    char t;
    int s;
    float h;
    short i;
    short q,q1;

    //clrscr();
     DB *tmp = new DB("\nБАЗА ДАННЫХ ¦1\n");

    for (int a=0; !a;){
    //clrscr();
     cout <<"1. Добавить запись\n"  ;
     cout <<"2. Удалить запись\n";
     cout <<"3. Сортировать базу\n";
     cout <<"4. Вывести базу\n";
     cout <<"5. Выход\n";
     cout <<"> ";
     int p;
     cin>>p;
     switch(p) {
     case 1: {
     cout<<"Наименование, Тип, Посевная площадь, Урожайность \n";

     //cin>>n;   // Закомментированные строки отвечают за чтение значений
     //cin>>t;    // переменных с клавиатуры и записи их в поля объекта.
     //cin>>s;    // Для удобства работы используется инициализация через
     //cin>>h;    // конструктор 3-х объектов.
     //tmp->add_rec( n, t, s, h ); 

         tmp->add_rec("Тотайдзи",'Т',220, 368.8f);
         tmp->add_rec("Якусидзи",'С',50, 12.7f);
         tmp->add_rec("Дайандзи",'Д',10, 12.2f);
     break;
     }

     case 2: {
     tmp->del_rec();
     break;
      }

     case 3: {
     tmp->sort_DB();
     break;
      }

      case 4: {
      cout<<*tmp;
      cout<<"\nНажмите клавишу для продолжения...";
      getch();
      break;
      }

      case 5: {
      a=1;
      break;
      }

      default :{
      cout << "Неверный вызов";
        getch();
        break;
      }
     }
    }
     return 0;
   }
```

```
const char* вот так должно быть или нет ? 
Обязательно нужно решить задачу через char. string не нужно применять! Спасибо ))
```

Answer (score 1):

А посмотреть внимательно?

```
void add_rec(char *a, char &b, int &c, float &d);
```

А вызываете как?

```
char *n;
char t;
unsigned int s;
float h;
....
tmp->add_rec( n, t, s, h );
```

Ну и как быть компилятору, если третьим параметром должен быть `int&`, а вы ему подсовываете `unsigned int`?

А, вы исправили код... ну что ж, тут

```
tmp->add_rec("Тотайдзи",'Т',220, 368.8f);
```

все еще хуже, потому что вы передали значения (rvalue), которые ссылками быть никак не могут, а первым - строковый литерал.

В С++ строковый литерал - это константный массив, каковой может приводиться к `const char*`, но не `char*`, так что и выше, в `add_rec`, и здесь

```
DB("\nБАЗА ДАННЫХ ¦1\n");
```

у вас сплошные проблемы...

Answer (score 0):

`char *n = new char[12];`

изменил строку на это и закомментировал

```
 `tmp->add_rec("Тотайдзи",'Т',220, 368.8f);
  tmp->add_rec("Якусидзи",'С',50, 12.7f);
  tmp->add_rec("Дайандзи",'Д',10, 12.2f)`
```

Теперь код работает